# Elixir/mix: ** (stop) :eacces on Windows

Tags: github, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

When I try to run 'iex -S mix phx.server', I get the error:

`iex(1)> 2020-07-26T05:13:18.632000Z error Task OrcasiteWeb.Endpoint started from #PID<0.857.0> terminating ** (stop) :eacces erlang.erl:2217: :erlang.open_port({:spawn_executable, 'c:/Program Files/nodejs/npm.cmd'}, [{:cd, "c:/workspace/orcasite/assets"}, :stderr_to_stdout, :use_stdio, :exit_status, :binary, :hide, {:args, ["run", "watch"]}]) (elixir 1.10.3) lib/system.ex:802: System.cmd/3 (phoenix 1.4.0) lib/phoenix/endpoint/watcher.ex:15: Phoenix.Endpoint.Watcher.watch/3 (elixir 1.10.3) lib/task/supervised.ex:90: Task.Supervised.invoke_mfa/2 (stdlib 3.12) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3 Function: &Phoenix.Endpoint.Watcher.watch/3 Args: ["npm", ["run", "watch"], [cd: "c:/workspace/orcasite/assets"]]`

This is similar to [this](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/2433) github issue as well as [this](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/683) one

I think the issue is the inverted backslashes in the paths since I'm on Windows 10, I was wondering how to install elixir/mix/phoenix so that this isn't an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I solved the issue by renaming npm.cmd to npm.bat in C:\Program Files\nodejs

Comment: Please delete the question or give a detailed correct answer.

Comment: I had the same issue and changing `.cmd` to `.bat` also fixed it. But why is this causing a permissions error? Were you able to work this out?